# Ajax response changing values each time it's sent

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a web crawler to get betting odds from a bookmaker. Their website is made entirely of AJAX requests and I have no experience of this or JS to be able to work out what's happening and what I can do to get the result I want.

My code so far uses Selenium to open a page and retrieve cookies necessary to send the API request and passes that, along with the headers and cookies then recursively send requests for the pages contained within;

```
headers = {
'Host': 'www.bet365.com',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
              'Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36',
'DNT': '1',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Referer': 'https://www.bet365.com/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}
r = requests.get(api, headers=headers, cookies=c)
for link in getLinks(r.text):
    print(requests.get('https://www.bet365.com/SportsBook.API/web? 
    lid=1&zid=1&'+link+'&cid=197&cgid=0', headers=headers, cookies=c).text)
```

I've gotten to the point that I emulate the AJAX call and send a request to the API which returns:
https://www.bet365.com/SportsBook.API/web?lid=1&zid=1&pd=%23AC%23B1%23C1%23D8%23E83884115%23F3%23G0%23H0%23I1%23P%5E13%23Q%5E43316955&cid=197&cgid=2

This feeds the page:
[https://www.bet365.com/#/AC/B1/C1/D8/E83884115/F3/G0/H0/I1/P^13/Q^43316955](https://www.bet365.com/#/AC/B1/C1/D8/E83884115/F3/G0/H0/I1/P%5E13/Q%5E43316955)

I can see the data I want in this response (the OD= values) however the value, which is what I'm actually interested in, changes every few seconds after refreshing to what seems like different encoded responses on a loop. The values do have a value that relates to the odds that are on the page as markets that have the same odds, have the same encoded values in the API response.
Examples of this are:

```
PA;ID=394840198;IT=83884115-394840198;NA=Galatasaray;OD=F^D;NF=83884115;
```

on the first request and then:

```
PA;ID=394840198;IT=83884115-394840198;NA=Galatasaray;OD=C[A;NF=83884115;
```

after refreshing. Both of these values mean odds of 2.4 as evidenced on the bet365 link above.

My question is, is there any way I can control which encoded value is served up to me via the request headers or something else as there is one that I actually want and can use easily but it seems like the server is sending a random encoding each time.

Comment: You should share some of your code. At this moment all is a miracle and would end up to do your whole job for free...(Without benefit but a lot afford)  So be so kind and show your code, and some data from your requests and be more explicit in your question.

Comment: You are looking at the prematch odds data. Then odds values are encrypted here. At live odds data you can get fresh odds, not encrypted odds. But you can't get the live odds just using API call. Please have a look at bet365 more

Comment: Share me the example of the full response of prematch result. Then I will let you know how you can decrypt this. The method is so easy but a little hard to found out before